# javascript comma separated list to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this type of list from javascript:

```
Amila,Asanka,Imaad,Kelum,Lakshan,Sagara,Thilina
```

I used the following code to convert to my output

```
var array = columnsload.split(",");
var string = JSON.stringify(columnsload);
var nameArray = string.split(',');
```

The output is like this :

```
"Amila,Asanka,Imaad,Kelum,Lakshan,Sagara,Thilina"
```

But I really need it like this :

```
["Amila","Asanka","Imaad","Kelum","Lakshan","Sagara","Thilina"]
```

Anyone know how to get output like this?

Comment: Remove the `JSON.stringify` line and your code will work as you need.

Comment: did my post answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Just do `var nameArray = columnsload.split(',');`. You dont need to `stringify` the array and then `split` it again, just one `.split` would be enough.

```
var columnsload = "Amila,Asanka,Imaad,Kelum,Lakshan,Sagara,Thilina";
var nameArray = columnsload.split(',');
console.log(nameArray);
```

If you need the whole thing to be string, you can run a `JSON.stringify` on the array after.

```
var columnsload = "Amila,Asanka,Imaad,Kelum,Lakshan,Sagara,Thilina";
var nameArray = columnsload.split(',');
console.log(JSON.stringify(nameArray));
// outputs ["Amila","Asanka","Imaad","Kelum","Lakshan","Sagara","Thilina"]
// as one string.
```

Comment: Thanks but i arrange my code like what you say but i need output like this ["Amila","Asanka","Imaad","Kelum","Lakshan","Sagara","Thilina"] but accorinding to your code its show like this  :Amila,Asanka,Imaad,Kelum,Lakshan,Sagara,Thilina

Comment: So, you need to output that `["Amila","Asanka","Imaad","Kelum","Lakshan","Sagara","Thilina"]` as a string?

Comment: Yes I need like as a stirng  Ill use this code for a bar chart there for i need a array like this but when i pass string array its not working

Comment: If that answers your question, please consider upvoting and marking it as the answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

the **split** function is enough to convert the string into an array;

```
 var names = "Amila,Asanka,Imaad,Kelum,Lakshan,Sagara,Thilina";
 var nameArr = names.split(",");
 console.log( nameArr );
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Hey I got the answer i used push method now its working                           var columnsload=   "Amila,Asanka,Imaad,Kelum,Lakshan,Sagara,Thilina";                                     var    array =columnsload.split(",");                                                  for(var i=0;i<array.length-1;i++){
     nameArray.push(array[i]);
}  output : ["Amila","Asanka","Imaad","Kelum","Lakshan","Sagara","Thilina"]

Comment: @Mogambo Hey, Why you are copying the array into  nameArray? you don't need to copy, use array directly